# Github Actions for project with Swift Package Manager dependency

Tags: ios, swift, github-actions, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to get Github Actions for project with Swift Package Manager dependency working.

I keep getting this error: `xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:15 The server SSH fingerprint failed to verify.`

... when Actions runs and Resolve Package Graph fetching the dependency in my project that uses Swift Package Manager.

My step it is failing on:

```
- name: Build and Test
  run: |
     xcodebuild clean test -project xyz.xcodeproj -scheme xyz -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.3,name=iPhone 8" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

I've tried adding `for ip in $(dig @8.8.8.8 github.com +short); do ssh-keyscan github.com,$ip; ssh-keyscan $ip; done 2>/dev/null >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` per [Xcode 11 resolving packages fails with SSH fingerprint](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-11-resolving-packages-fails-with-ssh-fingerprint/10388) but still can't get it to work, I might be putting it in the wrong place or doing it wrong.

Has anyone got this working that can help me?

Comment: I had the same problem and decided to use packages with Https urls instead of ssh and it worked fine.

Comment: wow that totally worked, nice! happy to mark your answer as correct if you post it (even if its sort of a workaround)

Comment: Can you share your file? I still can't get it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and decided to use packages with https urls instead of ssh and it worked fine. If you don't need to access private repos then this is a viable solution.

Comment: Can you expand on this solution with a full example? I don't get what you mean.